# Error-Is Nothing condition in case of object

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a conditional code for `Object` such that if value/text is found in object (in my example it is JSONObject) then do something otherwise nothing. But when I run the code it is working only when found in object and shows "runtime error" when it is not found in object.

The code is:-

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim jsonText As String
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Dim jsonObject As Object('It is an object created )

myfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="JSON file (*.json), *.json", Title:="Get File", MultiSelect:=True)
Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile(myfile, ForReading)
jsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close
Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)
' Condition that if in jsonObect, "b2b" is found then 
    If Not jsonObject("b2b") Is Nothing Then
    For Each item In jsonObject("b2b")  '("inv")
    Sheet3.Cells(a, 2) = jsonObject("fp")
    Sheet3.Cells(a, 1) = item("ctin")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: use option explicit and declare all your variables. item is not declared in the above.

Comment: Sir Could you give me  the sample code???

Comment: Can you answer my questions in comments below ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather have JSON to test with but you could attempt to set `jsonObject("b2b")` into a new variable wrapped within an `On Error Resume Next` and then test that for `If Not Is Nothing`

```
Dim b2bObject As Object
Dim item As Variant '<<=== ? missing from your code
On Error Resume Next
Set b2bObject = jsonObject("b2b")
On Error GoTo 0

If Not b2bObject Is Nothing Then
    For Each item In b2bObject
        Sheet3.Cells(a, 2) = jsonObject("fp")
        Sheet3.Cells(a, 1) = item("ctin")
    Next
End If
```

If using in a loop you may wish to `Set b2bObject = Nothing` before `End If` as safeguard.

Comment: your code is not working. same error show "Object required", kindly suggest me another

Comment: On which line? My code shouldn’t produce an error though your code lines in the above might.

Comment: What object type is  jsonObject("b2b")?  Can you share example json for both cases? How is item declared in your code? Wat datatype is item actually?

Comment: Sir Following are my code of JSON:-   "b2b":[{"fp":"03-2018","inv":[{"inum":"I1","idt":"20-03-2018","val":20000,"pos":"03","rchrg":"N","inv_typ":"R","itms":[{"num":501,"itm_det":{"txval":15000,"rt":5,"iamt":750,"csamt":0}}]}]}

Comment: there is no _ctin_ in that. Also, note that you have a dictionary object so you need to Dim item As Variant (as in my code above)